# Query multiple tables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following tables

```
Customers (id, name)
CustomerPriceRelations (customer_id, sales_price_id) # jointable
SalesPrices (id, margin)
ProductSalesPrices (product_id, sales_price_id) # jointable
```

Given a customer and a product, i want to fetch the matching SalesPrice. I'm kind of stuck and would appreciate any help

Comment: This is a basic join query in SQL.  You should learn SQL basic if you want to use databases.

Comment: Nothing about `Rails` and `ActiveRecord` fix tags please and specify what kind of sql you use.

Comment: See this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is MSSQL which you probably aren't using, but it should help. Just walk the relations from what you know until you get what you don't know.

```
SELECT sp.id, sp.margin
FROM SalesPrices sp
LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductSalesPrices ps
    ON sp.id = ps.sales_price_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomerPriceRelations cr
    ON ps.sales_price_id = cr.sales_price_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers c
    ON cr.customer_id = c.id
WHERE c.id = <your customer id> AND ps.product_id = <your product id>
```

Comment: While this is relevant and correct, ActiveRecord in RoR offers much more semantic and "Rails" ways of doing this with AR query syntax.